# Is it possible to disallow fetching resources from different domains?

Tags: javascript

I have a website where I'd like to disallow loading resources from all domains except my own.
I know of a convoluted way to achieve this with fetch. But I would also like to block the loading of, for example an image tag or script file, if it is hosted on a different domain. Is it possible to achieve this using javascript? Other methods?

Comment: Why would you be in a situation where random resources would be loaded on your site?

Comment: This has probably to do with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: @VLAZ I am not in such a situation. From a security perspective, I'd like to know if it is possible.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware CORS is used for disallowing the loading of resources from the server perspective. I'd like to disallow them from the clients perspective.

Comment: @AceCrow then let's talk about security. Trying to protect from something that isn't happening and isn't likely to happen is not "security" without a threat vector, it's hard to come up with a good solution. How do you protect yourself from something falling on your head outside? There aren't generally random stuff falling outside that can hurt you. I guess you can wear a hard. But what if a cow falls on you, then? You're still going to get hurt. This is why a threat vector *is important*.

Comment: @VLAZ I simply wanted to know if it was possible. It seems that it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what a [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) is for.

You can add an HTTP response header which limits where resources can be loaded from.

For example if the HTML document is loaded with:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
```

…then it can only load resources (including images, scripts, Ajax data, iframe contents, ets.) from the same origin.

The documentation I linked to above describes how to apply more nuanced restrictions.